# Can you beat the game without visiting the human outpost in The Ur-Quan Masters?

Tags: star-control-2

Note: I am still somewhere around the early parts of the game, having befriended several of the alien species. I am unsure about any details of the victory condition (and in fact don't even know if there is one), and have only vague ideas about the overarching mysteries of the game. I would greatly appreciate hiding any spoilers from myself or others who are interested.

I am curious about whether it is possible to beat the game without visiting the human outpost altogether? AFAIK, it would be possible to get enough fuel from the Melnorme traders to last a long while if the player knew what they were doing.

If that is not possible, is it possible to avoid getting the radioactives from the Sol system? Let's say that the player's lander is destroyed on Mercury while having all the radioactives onboard, and they accidentally shoot any others they come across in the system. Is continuing from this point possible? What if the player has only a single unit of fuel?

These questions assume that the player will win all fights with the accompanying Earthling Cruiser, without any losses. However, not with the flagship (without great improvements).

Comment: Completing the game requires a special module to be installed on the flagship, which can only be done on the outpost. But this is the final thing you do in the game. But I am not sure how far you can actually get in the game before visiting the outpost (theoretically and practically)  .

Comment: I would be compelled to ask how far it is (theoretically) possible to get with each of these restrictions, but feel that that would be too difficult to give an exact answer to. Especially since this game is so open-ended.

Comment: I don't think that this question will be that hard to answer. That game has a quite devote fanbase which has likely already explored these questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I did not test this with the original game but with the open source clone [*The Ur-Quan Masters*](http://sc2.sourceforge.net/). While it is based on the original sourcecode and known to be extremely faithful to the original, there is no guarantee that it is mechanically identical to it in every regard.

> is possible to beat the game without visiting the human outpost altogether?

No, but you can get pretty far... theoretically. You problem number one is that you will likely get ripped apart by Slylandro probes. For unexplained reasons they will be far more numerous before allying with the outpost. Also, without the outpost you won't be able to get any replacement crewmembers, new flagship modules or new landers.

But when you somehow manage to survive under these conditions, you can *theoretically* get most things done in the game. If you want to give it a try: A source of bio-matter nearby to pay the Melnorme for fuel is the nearby Alpha Wolf system.

Unfortunately you can't finish the game. In order to do so you will need a special module on your flagship which needs to be installed at the outpost.

> is it possible to avoid getting the radioactives from the Sol system?

It doesn't matter where you get the material. An alternative source nearby is Gamma Centauri I which you can just about reach with the 10 units of fuel you start out with... if you get past the Slylandro probes.

Until then, the base is a source of free landers (if you have none) and free fuel (if you are barely out).

> What if you break your lander while collecting the radioactive material on Mercury?

Return to the starbase and they will give you a new one.

Comment: It's reported to be possible: http://onpon4.github.io/other/no-starbase-challenge-guide/index.html -- disclaimer: I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible.  i just did it.

You must win every fight you get into, because you will not have the escape feature that gets installed at Starbase.  You must preserve your crew carefully, since you can't replenish it.  The only currency that matters is the locations of rainbow worlds and biological data.  These are sold to the Melnorme for technology to protect the lander, fuel, and information.  The frequency of probe encounters is turned way up when you don't visit Starbase, so you have to deal with that first.  Spoilers follow

> I got Fwiffo at Pluto, picked up some bio data, and went toward Beta Corvi to get the probe destruct code.  I stopped at Epsilon Gruis along the way to ally with the Spathi, primarily to get the Umgah Caster when they disappear 6 months later, but also for the easy bio data.  I also stopped at Alpha Pavonis to get the Ur-Quan Warp Pod.  After getting the probe destruct code at Beta Corvi, I went straight to the Arilou to have them give me the Portal Spawner, also stopping at the rainbow world that is on the way.  From there, once you have the Portal Spawner the game is pretty open.  Avoid fights, get crew by visiting aliens who give/sell you fully-crewed ships (Pkunk, Druuge, ZFP), and do a lot of spam-saving to save your crew and avoid those fights.

Here's another guy's account of his no-Starbase run of the game, from a few years ago - http://www.star-control.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=817

Comment: A great answer! I'm not sure why your previous answer got deleted, as I certainly did not delete it. However, I am very glad to hear the details - thank you for posting this.

Comment: It was deleted because an answer just saying yes or no isn't an answer. The character limit is there for a reason; to ensure you elaborate on a just yes or no answer. And it seems to have worked; you've expanded on and improved your previous answer.

Comment: I am pretty sure that an answer saying just "yes" or "no" to a yes-no question actually IS an answer.  Is it going to rain today?   No elaboration is needed beyond the answer.  I have a reasonable position to gripe about the moderation saying that I failed to answer the question.

Comment: In the most pedantic sense, yes, it does.  For **here**, however, it does not.  You have a minimum of 30 characters.  Neither yes nor no hits that limit.  Elaborate.  Put in some effort.  Or don't, and have it deleted.  Take our [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn a bit more about how we work.  As a sidenote, the parts I deleted are totally irrelevant to actually answering the question, and thus don't belong.  Please remove them.

Comment: I would have appreciated the moderators at least waiting for the asker himself to request the details before deleting my post for being inadequate.  It certainly answered the asker's question, even though everyone seems to think it did not.  I did not get the opportunity to respond to Phillipp's request for details before the post was deleted.

Comment: That's because the post did not classify as an answer. We delete such. After its been edited, we can then undelete it. The point is, posts have to meet our quality standards, which it did not. You have all the time in the world to word it before posting. Once you do, its going to be curated like any other post.

Comment: You or your moderators deleted a more accurate answer to the question - because Philipp's answer is wrong - simply because it did not provide details.  It was an answer, despite your assertions that it did not classify as one.  Here, at this website, maybe it did not classify as an answer, but it was more correct than the answer that Philipp provided.  It is possible to do, and if I had not come back here to observe your zealous curation/moderation, then that incorrect answer would have continued to stand, with the deleted answer gone and forgotten, even though it was correct.

Comment: No, we deleted a non answer. Correct is irrelevant; you have to actually answer the question, and do it to our standards.  If you don't want to have more answers deleted, just meet our quality standards, and you'll have no issues. Its not zealotry; its pragmatism, and a long view.

Comment: I guess keeping incorrect information and deleting correct information is "pragmatism" and the "long view" around here.  Thanks for  explaining